# Basic SQL - Adding Year on Year Revenue Numbers

Tags: sql, join, union

So I'm a bit newer to SQL and am having trouble with joining multiple queries in a singular table.

I have no one to talk to about this at my company and need some basic advice on how to create tables with year on year numbers.

My basic scripts goes as follows and I'm not sure how to link the 2 so that I can show the revenue for 2 years side by side.

```
SELECT a.date_key, b.account_name,a.client_id,SUM(a.revenue) as "Revenue 2019" FROM spreadsheet as a
LEFT JOIN account_file as b on a.client_id = b.client_id
WHERE date_key >= 2019 and date_key < 2020. 
GROUP BY a.date_key, a.client_id, b.account_name


SELECT a.date_key, b.account_name,a.client_id,SUM(a.revenue) as "Revenue 2018" FROM spreadsheet as a
LEFT JOIN account_file as b on a.client_id = b.client_id
WHERE date_key >= 2018 and date_key < 2019. 
GROUP BY a.date_key, a.client_id, b.account_name
```

I have seen examples of how this is supposed to work but can't quite wrap my head around it and could use a hand.

Comment: It is very hard to help you unless you show example tables and what you expect as a result. Would suggest that you add that.

Comment: user inner join and make sure compare the primary key that has been passed to another table like foreign key

Comment: can you post the two tables structure or post the tables screenshots?

Comment: Hi all, this was just a quick example of the issue since I know that I'm missing a fundamental, not an actual scenario.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use conditional aggregation but do not use `datekey` in the `GROUP BY` column as follows:

```
SELECT a.account_name, s.client_id,
       SUM(CASE WHEN s.date_key >= 2019 AND s.date_key < 2020 
                THEN s.revenue 
            END) AS "Revenue 2019",
       SUM(CASE WHEN s.date_key >= 2018 AND s.date_key < 2019 
                THEN s.revenue 
           END) AS "Revenue 2018"
FROM spreadsheet AS s
LEFT JOIN account_file AS a 
    ON s.client_id = a.client_id
WHERE s.date_key >= 2018 AND s.date_key < 2020
GROUP BY a.account_name, s.client_id
```

Comment: Thank you Tejash, this is exactly what I need for a foundation.

Comment: You should accept this answer if it resolved your issue so thay this queation is marked as resolved.

Comment: No @Parfait, your answer is clearly wrong.. see the group by clause of your answer.

Comment: Ah yes! Didn't catch that. Likely with data, I would see it better. Also, if OP wants to extend to other years, may not need `WHERE` in your solution.

Comment: Yes that is upto OP.

Answer (score 0):

Consider conditional aggregation where you move your `WHERE` conditions to `CASE` statements for multiple columns. Also please heed [Bad habits to kick : using table aliases like (a, b, c) or (t1, t2, t3)](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-table-aliases-like-a-b-c-or-t1-t2-t3)

```
SELECT a.account_name
       , s.client_id
       , SUM(CASE 
                  WHEN s.date_key >= 2019 AND s.date_key < 2020 
                  THEN s.revenue 
             END) AS "Revenue 2019"
       , SUM(CASE
                  WHEN s.date_key >= 2018 AND s.date_key < 2019 
                  THEN s.revenue 
             END) AS "Revenue 2018"
       ... 

FROM spreadsheet AS s
LEFT JOIN account_file AS a 
    ON s.client_id = a.client_id
GROUP BY a.account_name
         , s.client_id
```

Comment: Thank you Parfait this is excellent and thank you also for the Bad Habits link.